# Large (solvable) equation systems as inputs to test gaussian equation solver

Tags: java, algorithm, gaussian, bubble-sort, equation-solving

I have coded an equation solver using gaussian elimination. The input is units that are to be sorted by their size relative to the largest unit (example output 1l = 10dl = 100cl = 1000ml). I have example inputs that the code handles well, but on some unknown code for a test it crashes. Is there anywhere one could find test inputs to use for debugging (equation systems that are solvable)? The input should only yield integer solutions and preferably be between 2 to 10 variable equations

Comment: Can't you just create random problems?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're solving here.  Typical Gaussian elimination doesn't guarantee integer solutions.  I have no way to tell if your system of equations is ill conditions.  All systems of equations are not guaranteed to have solutions.  Besides, who uses Gaussian elimination?  LU decomposition with pivoting is a better idea.

Comment: I know, but the test cases I get are provided such that they guarantee positive integer solutions. I guess the problem is pretty specific, but all I asked for was if anyone knew somewhere where there are any linear equation systems that one could use to test such algorithms with @duffymo

Comment: That seems time consuming if they are supposed to be solvable and 10 variables for example @NicoSchertler

Comment: Why is it time consuming? Generate a random matrix and a random solution vector that respects your constraints (positive, integer). Then calculate the right-hand side and use it to re-calculate the solution vector. Then, compare. Ensuring solvability is a bit trickier, but doable: When you create the matrix row by row, check that the new row does not lie in the span of the previous rows (e.g. using an equivalent orthonormal system of rows).

Comment: True, I did not think about that, but it's kind of what I ended up doing. Solved it btw @NicoSchertler